# I suddenly have no audio on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound

I don't think I've recently updated anything, but I suddenly found myself with no audio coming out of HDMI. On 3.5 jack on the motherboard only the left channel works. Bluetooth devices work only in mono.

I've ruled out hardware defects as the setup works fine under Windows.

The only clue I've got is the image attached. I don't remember having the last two lines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal, and enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work, and same lines on startup

Comment: so when you open the sound settings you found no audio devices there ?

Comment: 'alsactl restore'
#If that didn't suffice
'alsactl init'

Comment: and don't forget to reboot

Comment: all it did was make boot times longer and added these errors https://imgur.com/a/NIxIsqc  even before i could see optical audio and in built audio options, but i have no sound still. btw i have rx 580 (which i use hdmi for monitor audio ) and i7 3770 if its of any use